# Can't fetch R updates

Tags: synaptic, r

since my version of R is not compatible with a package I need for my work I wanted to update it today but received the following error message when trying to download the updates with synaptic:

> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ftp.yalwa.org/cran/bin/linux/debian/squeeze-cran/r-base-core_2.15.0-1~squeezecran.0_amd64.deb
>   Could not resolve 'ftp.yalwa.org'
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ftp.yalwa.org/cran/bin/linux/debian/squeeze-cran/r-cran-boot_1.3-4-1~squeezecran.2.15.0_all.deb
>   Could not resolve 'ftp.yalwa.org'
>
> ... and several other messages all pointing towards yalwa.org , can't post them due to spam prevention

well the given urls seem to be outdated, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

I don't know anything about ftp.yalwa.org, so I can't recommend you remove these lines from the file. However you should add the proper CRAN mirrors.

From [this page](http://cran.r-project.org/):

> For a backport of the latest R release to squeeze, simply add
>   something like
>
> deb http://<favorite-cran-mirror>/bin/linux/debian squeeze-cran/
>
> to
>   the file /etc/apt/sources.list on your computer and install as usual.
>   Note that you need to substitute <favorite-cran-mirror> by one of the
>   mirror URLs listed in
>
> http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html

The instructions mention Squeeze (the current stable release of Debian), but it should (I think) work with any version of Synaptic you're using.

**Possible Exception**

Maybe you're not running your version of (I'm assuming) Linux on a PC/laptop/x86 architecture. The repositories only contain binaries for this platform. If you're running something else (like ARM or SPARC), you should compile the binaries yourself from source.

> There are binaries for the i386 and amd64 architectures. You can use
>   the source packages from
>
> deb-src http://<favorite-cran-mirror>/bin/linux/debian squeeze-cran/
>
> to compile binaries for other platforms.

**Once you update /etc/apt/sources.list/**
Run the following:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: nice answer, not only solved the problem but also told me how to edit the sourcelist - thx for it

Answer (score 0):

Go to the CRAN web site, there you'll find instructions on pointing apt-get at a CRAN mirror to get the latest. Here is the [debian page](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/)